# Why My Navigation Menu disappears when I resize the browser. What should I add in the Jquery to prevent this?

Tags: jquery, css, navigation

I have a simple Navigation Menu. I have added a media Query and the breakpoint is 400px. Everything is working perfect except one thing, whenever I expand the menu in Mobile view and then click on the Close button, everything works fine. But the problem arises when I resize the browser from mobile to PC version, whole menu disappears. What should I add in my JQuery code to prevent this Problem?

**Note:** 
Whenever the Menu is expanded and I resize the window, it doesn’t disappear. And I am not taking care of styling the PC Version yet. I will style it later once this issue is resolved.
The Link is Below. Please have a look at it.
[(JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/naeemrind/3ykyLqvh/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="close"><p>CLOSE</p></div>
        <div class="menu-trigger"><div id="arrow">&#9660;</div><p>MENU</p></div>
        <div class="nav-menu">
           <ul>
               <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
               <li><a href="#" class="projects">Projects<div id="arrow-1">&#9660;</div></a>
                   <ul>
                       <li><a href="#">JQuery</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Web App</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#">Website</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </li>
               <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Links</a></li>
               <li><a href="#">Current Projects</a></li>
            </ul> 
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
div .nav-menu {
    background: #e7e7e7;
    padding: 0 20px;
}
.nav-menu ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.nav-menu ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
}
.nav-menu ul li a:link, .nav-menu ul li a:visited {
    display: block;
    font-size: 90%;
    padding: 10px 25px;
    color: #305782;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.menu-trigger {
    display: none;
    color: #305782;
    background: #d5dce4;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
    font-size: 90%;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-trigger p {
    line-height: 6px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    margin-bottom: 7px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    font-size: 1.3em;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}


@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    .menu-trigger {
    display: block;
    }
    .nav-menu ul li {
        float: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
    }
    .nav-menu ul li:last-child {
        border-bottom: 0;
    }
    .nav-menu {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-menu ul ul {
        display: none;
    }
    .nav-expanded {        /* will be added through jQuery */
        display: block;
    }
    .background {         /* will be added through jQuery */
        color: #d6d6d6;
        background: #153448;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }
    .background-1 {        /* will be added through jQuery */
        background: #2f5269;
        color: aliceblue !important;
        transition: 0.5s;
    }

    #arrow {            /* For the Main Menu Arrow */
        margin-right: 340px;
        font-size: 1.4em;
        line-height: 0;
        position: absolute;
        left: 25px;
        top: 28px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }
    #arrow-1 {            /* For the SubMenu Arrow, Projects */
        float: right;
        margin-right: 15px;
        transition: 0.4s;
    }
    .rotated {           /* For Arrow, will be added through jQuery */
        transform: rotate(-180deg);
    }
    .close {
        position: absolute;
        right: 10px;
        top: 9px;
        background: #d5dce4;
        color: aliceblue;
        text-align: right;
        width: 310px;
        height: 36px;
        z-index: 99;
        cursor: pointer;
        display: none;
    }
    .close p {
        padding-right: 15px;   
        line-height: 5px;
        text-align: right;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        color: black;
    }
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $(".menu-trigger").click(function(){
                    $(".nav-menu").slideDown(400);
                    $("#arrow").toggleClass("rotated");
                    $(".close").fadeIn(); 
                    $(".menu-trigger p").css("color", "#909090");
                 });

                /* For Sub Menu Projects */
                $(".projects").click(function(){
                    $(".nav-menu ul ul").slideToggle();
                    $(".projects").toggleClass("background-1");
                    $("#arrow-1").toggleClass("rotated");
                    $(".nav-menu ul ul li a").css({"background":"#687583", "color":"white"});
                });  
                /* For Closing All Menus */
                $(".close").click(function(){
                    $(this).fadeOut();
                    $(".nav-menu").slideUp(); 
                    $(".nav-menu ul ul").slideUp();
                    $("#arrow-1").removeClass("rotated");
                    $(".projects").removeClass("background-1");
                    $(".menu-trigger p").fadeIn();
                    $(".menu-trigger p").css("color", "#3c3c3c");
                    $("#arrow").toggleClass("rotated");
                });
            });
```

Comment: because you have made this menu to work for mobile devices that has max width 400px

Comment: Yes I just figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the .slideUp() function the display property of the element is set to "none". So your .nav-menu keeps "display: none;" after you close your mobile menu. This makes the menu stay hidden after you resize the browser window to desktop size.

Comment: A short (but probably not so elegant) solution would be to check the width of your window and change the display value of your .nav-menu object to "block" when the width is more than 400

Comment: Thanks, You gave me a good clue. I went to Codepen and found a Pen about JQuery **MatchMedia** and used it in my site. It worked :)